# An advice about parameters in opencv_traincascade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, emgucv, haar-classifier

I am doing a project that consists in recognize a banana using haar features. I am using EMgucv and visual studio 2010 for that. I am using opencv_createsamples and opencv_traincascade.I have a question about parmeters. What happen if I increase those values?
I set:

-numPos 3800
-nunNeg 6000
-numStages 16
-minHitRate 0.999
-maxfalseAlarmRate 0.3
but I want to know What are maxWeakCount and maxdetph parameters? What means? I want and example to understand that

Comment: Anybody can answer my question??